# Is my Update function correct (PHP)

Tags: php, sql

I get an error:

> **Fatal error:** Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message >'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 
>   You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''1'WHERE name_enterprise='111'' at line 1' in 
>   C:\wamp\www\project\models\Db.class.php on line 29.

I would like to know if my query is correct, thanks in advance.

```
   public function update_enterprise2($name_enterprise,$address_enterprise){
        $query = 'UPDATE enterprises SET name_enterprise='. $this->_db->quote($name_enterprise) .',address_enterprise'. $this->_db->quote($address_enterprise).'WHERE name_enterprise=' . $this->_db->quote($name_enterprise);
        $this->_db->prepare($query)->execute();
    }
```

Comment: You're missing an `=` after `address_enterprise`. Does that solve the issue?

Comment: Use prepared statements with parameters and syntax errors become *much* easier to find.

Comment: debugging 101. echo the bloody query.

Comment: You need put a "=" caracter before address_enterprise and a space before the "where"

Comment: @Michael You were right, I had forgotten then '=' Thanks to everyone for their help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you set up a prepared statement.

```
function update_enterprise2($name_enterprise, $address_enterprise) {
    $query = '
            UPDATE enterprises SET 
                name_enterprise = :name_enterprise,
                address_enterprise = :address_enterprise
            WHERE 
                name_enterprise = :name_enterprise2
            ';
    if ($con = $this->_db->prepare($query)) {
        $con->execute([
            ':name_enterprise' => $name_enterprise,
            ':address_enterprise' => $address_enterprise,
            ':name_enterprise2' => $name_enterprise,
        ]);
    }
}
```

note that you can only use names parameters once, so you need to change the name in order to use them twice.